# copy files from C:\ to another location with four characters or less

Tags: command-line

I need to copy the files with filenames that have four characters or less and .TMP extension into a folder.  Can this be done with one command if they are in one location?

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

> COPY [SOURCE]\????.TMP [DESTINATION]

Where `[SOURCE]` is the source drive/folder and `[DESTINATION]` is the destination drive/folder.

Comment: Sorry Im really new at this so hang with me here. When I run dir COPY [SOURCE]\????.TMP [DESTINATION] first its pulling more than four character files names.

Comment: @OCGIRL: Don't combine dir and copy obviously, since they are separate commands. Just try `dir [SOURCE]\????.TMP`

Comment: lol no I didn't combine copy and dir.  I'm new but not that much of a newbie.  Thanks again.

Comment: @OCGIRL: Your comment above strongly suggested you did combine them, since you used `dir copy ...`, unless you meant that you ran those two commands separately which wasn't at all clear. Anyway, good that you got it to work. Don't forget to thank RockPaperLizard by [accepting](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) his answer.

Comment: @OCGIRL Glad it worked for you :-)  Happy to help.